# ruby conditions using && and ||

Tags: ruby, conditional-statements

I can't figure how to correctly write the rule

I want express the following rule:

> If conclusion is 'negative' one of the premises must be negative.

Here's how I tried to write this.

```
def test4b
    if (@conclusion.getQuality == 'negative' && (@major.getQuality != 'negative' || @minor.getQuality != 'negative')) 
    validity = "invalid (4b) Negative conclusion without a negative premise"
    else
        validity = "pass"
    end
end
```

But this isn't working. It seems to exclude every syllogism with a negative premise. Again, I only want to exclude syllogisms where which have a negative conclusion without any negative premises.

Comment: In Ruby, you should use `snake_case` for method names and omit a `get` prefix for getters, i.e. `@conclusion.quality == 'negative'` or better yet a predicate method: `@conclusion.negative?`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be:

```
if (@conclusion.getQuality == 'negative' && (@major.getQuality != 'negative' && @minor.getQuality != 'negative'))
```

Both of `@major` and `@minor` are not to be 'negative'.
Your method is to retrun the logical value of `!conclusion => (!major || !minor)`. The negation of this expression would be:

```
!conclusion && !(!major || !minor) <=> !conclusion && major && major
```

(DeMorgan's law). This is the condition youa re lloking for, note there are no `||` here.

Also note that it would be more readable though if you do:

```
if (@conclusion.getQuality == 'negative' && [@major, @minor].all? {|m| m.getQuality != 'negative'})
```

or

```
if (@conclusion.getQuality == 'negative' && ![@major, @minor].any? {|m| m.getQuality == 'negative'})
```

Comment: I think another option is `[@major, @minor].none? {|m| m.getQuality == 'negative'}`, which basically mirrors the natural language quite well.